# Store a "list" in hdf5 file as Dataset

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I have a `blobArray` of data type `list`.

```
>>> type(blobArray)
list
```

```
>>> blobArray
[[],[],[],[<KeyPoint 0x7f38e522dc90>],[<KeyPoint 0x7f38e522d900>],[],....]
```

I am trying to create a dataset and store it in HDF5 file.

```
dset1 = hf.create_dataset("name", data=blobArray)
```

This is returning an error

```
TypeError: Object dtype dtype('O') has no native HDF5 equivalent
```

Changing to ndarray will not help as creating an ndarray from ragged nested sequences is deprecated.

What can I do?

Comment: What's a `Keypoint`?

Comment: i was detecting circles in an image. Keypoints are the location of the same.

Comment: I think you need to use `pickle` for a compound object like that.  `hdf5` is best for `numpy` arrays, especially numeric.

Comment: Your question is primarily about the data schema, not the api functions. You need to map your blobArray object to match a HDF5 schema. From there you can write the data to a file with h5py, pytables, C++ or FORTRAN. Which you use depends on the schema. HDF5 can handle compound data types, but each API provides different levels of support. For example, h5py works with numpy objects. pytables has better coverage.